# fortran: using pgplot with eclipse photran

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran, photran

So I am really not a Fortran programmer at all, but I have some code I am working with that uses the pgplot graphics libraries in fortran. I am able to get the code running in fortran from the console using the following commands.

```
gfortran -o simple discrete.f -lpgplot -IX11
```

discrete.f is the name of the file. So this works when I run it from the console. However, I want to run the code in the eclipse photran plugin so that I can use the debugger so that I can step through the code and observe some of the variables. I tried to put the -lpgplot and -IX11 flags in Eclipse, but I am getting errors about pgbbuf and pgnumb_ functions as undefined reference (which means that the -lpgplot function is not working when called from eclipse.

Can anyone please tell me how to set the flags correctly to run this code in Photran so that I can compile it and see the pgplot figure come up?

I am adding the console output:

```
02:57:05 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project burglar_code_martin ****
make clean 
rm -rf  ./burglary_model.o  burglar_code_martin


02:57:05 Build Finished (took 61ms)

02:57:05 **** Build of configuration Debug for project burglar_code_martin ****
make all 
Building file: ../burglary_model.f
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -I/usr/lib -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lpgplot -IX11 -o "burglary_model.o" "../burglary_model.f"
Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 225
Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 228
../burglary_model.f:155.27:

            call probcheck(frac,1,outc)                                 
                           1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'problist' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
../burglary_model.f:54.33:

                  call probcheck(robprob,1,outcome)                     
                                 1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'problist' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
../burglary_model.f:95.30:

               call probcheck(placeprob,1,outcome)                      
                              1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'problist' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
../burglary_model.f:206.36:

      subroutine output(A,burgsatloc,t,l,pic,screen,A0,Bbar)            
                                    1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'burgsatloc' at (1)
../burglary_model.f:206.44:

      subroutine output(A,burgsatloc,t,l,pic,screen,A0,Bbar)            
                                            1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'pic' at (1)
../burglary_model.f:206.51:

      subroutine output(A,burgsatloc,t,l,pic,screen,A0,Bbar)            
                                                   1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'screen' at (1)
../burglary_model.f:145.32:

      integer l,pic,screen,i,j,k,PGOPEN,burgsatloc(512,*),nbar,outc     
                                1
Warning: Unused variable 'k' declared at (1)
../burglary_model.f:146.15:

      real rand,red,green,blue                                          
               1
Warning: Unused variable 'rand' declared at (1)
../burglary_model.f:143.53:

      subroutine initialize(burgsatloc,B,l,pic,screen,rbar,Bbar)        
                                                     1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'screen' at (1)
../burglary_model.f:4.58:

      integer i,j,n,l,pic,screen,guy,burgsatloc(512,512),k,             
                                                          1
Warning: Unused variable 'k' declared at (1)
Finished building: ../burglary_model.f

Building target: burglar_code_martin
Invoking: GNU Fortran Linker
gfortran -lpgplot -IX11 -o "burglar_code_martin"  ./burglary_model.o   
./burglary_model.o: In function `output_':
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:241: undefined reference to `pgbbuf_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:242: undefined reference to `pgnumb_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:244: undefined reference to `pgenv_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:246: undefined reference to `pglab_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:247: undefined reference to `pgimag_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:253: undefined reference to `pgebuf_'
./burglary_model.o: In function `initialize_':
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:165: undefined reference to `pgopen_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:168: undefined reference to `pgpap_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:169: undefined reference to `pgask_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:170: undefined reference to `pgscir_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:175: undefined reference to `pgscr_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:181: undefined reference to `pgscr_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:187: undefined reference to `pgscr_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:193: undefined reference to `pgscr_'
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:199: undefined reference to `pgscr_'
./burglary_model.o: In function `implicit':
/media/jaimini/workspace/eclipsejuno/burglar_code_martin/Debug/../burglary_model.f:109: undefined reference to `pgclos_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [burglar_code_martin] Error 1

02:57:05 Build Finished (took 209ms)
```

Comment: Try replacing `-lpgplot` with `-L/full/path/to/libpgplot.XX` where the `XX` is the appropriate file extension of libpgplot.

Comment: So I actually ended up switching to Netbean 7.3. The Netbeans compiler settings were much easier to adjust, and that worked. I was actually able to keep the -lgplot setting as it was and it worked. Thanks Kyle.